# Error during installing skype , software update and while starting ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, update-manager, dpkg

when installing skype on ubuntu 12.04 Lts gets the following error

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
[sudo] password for shailendra: 
dpkg: error: unknown option --add-architecture

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use `dselect' or `aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through `less' or `more' !


$ sudo dpkg--add-architecture i386
sudo: dpkg--add-architecture: command not found
```

My ubuntu is 12.04 LTS OS type 64 bit
Trying to install it through commands

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

it gives the above mentioned error
Also while software updates getting message

```
locale:cannot set LC_ctype to default locale: no such file or directory
                  LC_MESSAGES, LC_ALL no such file or directory
```

I have an error at the start before entering my identity to start ubuntu

```
The disc2 drive for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 not mounted or unmount
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you already download skype

```
wget http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-linux-beta-ubuntu-64
```

A file named getskype-linux-beta-ubuntu-64 has been downloaded in your home directory. This is the latest Skype package.

Add the 32bit architecture

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```

Install some essential 32-bit packages

```
sudo apt-get -f install -y
sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386 -y
```

Finally, install skype package

```
sudo dpkg --install getskype-linux-beta-ubuntu-64
```

(Note: If you was to use the software centre for installation, you should add ".deb" at the end)

[Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2171120)

Comment: When I try to do sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
[sudo] password for shailendra: 
dpkg: error: unknown option --add-architecture

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use `dselect' or `aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;